# Python - comparing numbers. I am comparing 1 with 1 but it is failing - please see code - Can anyone tell me what is the issue?

Tags: python, relational-operators

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    strSize = input()
    inpt  = input()

    strArrSize = strSize.split()
    if (len(strArrSize) ==2):
        n = strArrSize[0]
        m = strArrSize[1]

        inptArray = inpt.split()

        print(n)
        print(len(inptArray))

        if (n == len(inptArray)):
            print("true")
        else:
            print("Given " + str(n) + " integers but entered " + str(len(inptArray)))
    else:
        print("Invalid itnput. The first line must have two space seperated integers.")
```

Here is the input and output I got.

PS S:\Study\CH1> python tt.py

1 2

1

1

1

Given 1 integers but entered 1

Comment: You're probably comparing a `str` type with an `int`.

Comment: to convert, use something like `str(1)` or `int('1')`

Comment: Note that whatever is passed to `input()` is stored as a `str`

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Understood.

Answer (score 2):

When you compare `n == len(inptArray)`, they are not equal because `n` is a `str` and `len(inptArray)` is an `int`.

When you set `n` and `m`, cast them to `int` types.

```py
n = int(strArrSize[0])
m = int(strArrSize[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's debug this by checking the values:

```
    print('|'+n+'|', type(n))
    print(len(inptArray))
```

Output:

```
|1| <class 'str'>
1
```

`input` returns strings.  When you split that, you get a smaller string.  Thus, `n` is a string value.  `len` returns an integer.  Since these are of different basic types, they cannot be equal.

Fix this with `n = int(strArrSize[0])`.  You will likely want to do the same with `m`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to make sure you're comparing like with like. Comparing `'1' == 1` will give `False` because you're comparing `str` with `int`.

Here's one way of correcting it:

```
strSize = input()
inpt  = input()

strArrSize = strSize.split()
if (len(strArrSize) ==2):
    n = strArrSize[0]
    m = strArrSize[1]

    inptArray = inpt.split()

    print(n)
    print(len(inptArray))

    if (int(n) == len(inptArray)):
        print("true")
    else:
        print("Given " + str(n) + " integers but entered " + str(len(inptArray)))
else:
    print("Invalid itnput. The first line must have two space seperated integers.")
```

Or as other answers have said, you can convert to `int` when you assign `n` and `m`.

Comment: When you post an answer involving code, please *explain* what you're doing.  This raw-code answer leaves the OP to search through all of this to find what changed -- a single term in the `if` statement is all that I see.  For such a small change, why did you post the entire main program?  Perhaps I'm missing something else.

Comment: I had commented what the problem was below the question, so I just posted this to show where the edit should be made.

Comment: Each question and answer should be self-contained.  Someone coming to the archive a year from now shouldn't have to read the entire thread to understand what you're doing.  Note that I'm *not* down-voting -- I'm hoping to get your answer into better shape, using principles my predecessors taught me.

Comment: I've added a bit more. Thanks for your input.